# Jquery autocomplete not displaying selected list in asp.net page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have the asp.net page(aspx), from that page I called my WebApi service and get list of string to jquery auto complete source object.service returns all the data but the not showing in the page.

My Web api method:
It returns list of strings.

```
[HttpPost]
public List<string> GetAgencyCPR(string CPR, string Agency)<br/>
{
   return cc.AgencyInsured.FindAll(c => c.CPR != null).Select(e => 
   e.CPR).ToList();
}
```

My Script on the page:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        BindControls();
    })

    function BindControls() {

          $("#<%=txtSearchCPR.ClientID%>").autocomplete(               
            {
                source: function (request, response) {
                    var val = request.term;
                    $.ajax({

                        url: "Http://localhost:7050" + "/api/admin/getagencycpr/" + val + "/" + "BBK",
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map((data), function (item) {
                                return
                                {
                                    value: item;
                                }
                            }));
                        },
                        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert(textStatus);
                        }

                    });
                },
                minLength: 1,

            });
    }
```

Comment: Can you add a minimal example of our source code that illustrates your problem?

Comment: Web API Method:[HttpPost]
public List<string> GetAgencyCPR(string CPR, string Agency)
{
   return cc.AgencyInsured.FindAll(c => c.CPR != null).Select(e => e.CPR).ToList();
}

Comment: You can edit your question and add the code example there. It seems that you tried to post the code as comment.

Comment: Added in the question

Comment: @sathiyabharathi Have you checked browser's developer console for any error?

Comment: No error on browser console.but the item not listed